# My program to model exterior ballistics doesn't doesn't produce the plot I expect

Tags: programming, broken-code

Here is my program to model exterior ballistics. It doesn't doesn't produce the plot I expect. How can I fix it?

```
program[V_, o_, m_, k_] :=
  Module[{dt, lista, gr, Vx, Vy, r, g},
    dt = 0.01;
    x[0] = 0;
    y[0] = 0;
    Vx[0] = V*Cos[o];
    Vy[0] = V*Sin[o];
    r[0] = 1.2;
    i = -1;
    g[0] = 9.83;
    While[y[i] >= 0,
      i = i + 1;
      Vx[i + 1] = Vx[i] - (r[i]*k*(Vx[i])^2*dt*(Cos[o])^3)/m;
      Vy[i + 1] = Vy[i] - (k*(Vy[i])^2*dt*(Sin[o])^3)/m - g[i]*dt;
      r[i + 1] = r[0]*(1 - (6.5*10^-3*y[i])/293)^2.5;
      g[i + 1] = (3.99*10^14)/(6371*1000 + y[i])^2;
      x[i + 1] = x[i] + Vx[i]*dt;
      y[i + 1] = y[i] + Vy[i]*dt;];
    lista = Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 1000}];
    gr = ListPlot[lista];
    Show[gr, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Come on! Do you really think that we can guess what the problem might be?! What should your code do?

Comment: for one thing you never enter the loop because `y[-1]` is not defined.

Comment: A nice answer has been posted for you below. But I have a couple of suggestions if you have future questions. (1) Follow MarcoB's suggestion for explaining your code; "It doesn't doesn't produce the plot I expect" is not specific enough. What *should* it look like vs what *does* it look like? (2) Format your code nicely. Click the grey question mark at the top of the toolbar for help. (3) Thoroughly consult the *Mathematica* documentation before asking your question. (4) Search the site for a possible duplicate question first. (5) Follow the suggestions in Lou's post above.

Comment: @MarcoB. If we read the code carefully, we can see it models the exterior ballistics of a projectile. It is actually a rather nice model.

Answer (score 17):

I am answering because I was curious as to what exactly was the problem, and from my investigation, it is clear you need to learn basic debugging techniques. So, I will walk you through how I did it.  First, I ran it with some "reasonable" values for the arguments

```
p1 = program[5, Pi, 1, 1]
```

which returned a plot with what appears to be a single point in it. To confirm, I ran this

```
Cases[p1, _Point, -1]
(* {Point[{{0., 0.}}]} *)
```

So, we need to find out why only one point is being generated. To do this, we need to examine `lista`. The simplest method is to comment stuff out in the definition of `program`, e.g.

```
lista = Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 1000}](*;
gr = ListPlot[lista];
Show[gr, PlotRange -> All]*)
```

as the last lines in `program`, and then we re-run it

```
p2 = program[5, Pi, 1, 1]
(* {{0, 0}, {x[1], y[1]}, {x[2], y[2]}, ...} *)
```

So, `x[i]` and `y[i]` are not getting updated when `i >= 1`. The issue is the condition used in the `While`:

```
y[i] > 0
```

But,

```
i = -1
```

so `While` is *never* run. We fix this by setting

```
i = 0
```

and moving the increment code

```
i = i + 1;
```

to the end of the `While` loop. Then, we recheck

```
p3 = program[5, Pi, 1, 1]
(* {{0, 0}, {-0.05, 0.}, {-0.097, -0.000983}, {x[3], y[3]}, ... }*)
```

So, it is only a partial fix. We need to update the `Table` iterator to only iterate out to `i`, e.g.

```
lista = Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, i}]
```

Then, re-running, we see that `lista` only returns the available 3 points. There is one more bug present in your code: `x` and `y` are not localized, so setting

```
x = 5
```

prior to running `program` will cause issues. So, they need to be localized,

```
program[V_,o_,m_,k_]:= Module[{dt,gr,Vx,Vy,r,g, x, y, i},
  dt=0.01;
  x[0]=0;
  y[0]=0;
  Vx[0]=V*Cos[o];
  Vy[0]=V*Sin[o];
  r[0]=1.2;
  i=0;
  g[0]=9.83;
  While[y[i]>=0,
    Vx[i+1]=Vx[i]-(r[i]*k*(Vx[i])^2*dt*(Cos[o])^3)/m;
    Vy[i+1]=Vy[i]-(k*(Vy[i])^2*dt*(Sin[o])^3)/m-g[i]*dt;
    r[i+1]=r[0]*(1-(6.5*10^-3*y[i])/293)^2.5;
    g[i+1]=(3.99*10^14)/(6371*1000+y[i])^2;
    x[i+1]=x[i]+Vx[i]*dt;
    y[i+1]=y[i]+Vy[i]*dt;
    i=i+1;
  ];
  ListPlot[Table[{x[i],y[i]},{i,0,i}], PlotRange->All]
]
```

I also took the liberty of simplifying your graphics code.

Comment: On your way to a deserved Reversal badge :)

Comment: @belisarius that would be two of them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88709/152358